# Matplotlib and Tkinter Real time Plot (AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'update' Exception in Tkinter callback)

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

I am currently trying to graph the data sent from the submit button, but after reaching 100 iterations the program gives me an error, but if I implement random numbers it works without problem, do you know why this happens ?, any suggestion that can you give me it would be very useful, thanks and regards

```
import tkinter as tk
import time
import collections
import matplotlib, matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import random


class Aplicacion():
    def __init__(self, plotLength = 100):
        self.raiz = tk.Tk()
        self.raiz.configure(bg = 'beige')
        self.raiz.title('Aplicación')

        self.plotMaxLength = plotLength
        self.data = collections.deque([0] * plotLength, maxlen=plotLength)
        self.plotTimer = 0
        self.previousTimer = 0

        self.entry = tk.Entry(self.raiz)
        self.entry.insert(0, '0')
        self.entry.pack(padx=5)
        SendButton = tk.Button(self.raiz, text='Send', command=self.send)
        SendButton.pack(padx=5)
        self.send()
        self.main()

    def send(self):
        self.val = self.entry.get()
        print(self.val)

    def tag1(self, frame, lines, lineValueText, lineLabel, timeText):

        currentTimer = time.clock()
        self.plotTimer = int((currentTimer - self.previousTimer) * 1000)
        self.previousTimer = currentTimer
        timeText.set_text('Muestreo = ' + str(self.plotTimer) + 'ms')

        value, = [self.val]
        #value = random.randint(1, 10)
        self.data.append(value)
        lines.set_data(range(self.plotMaxLength), self.data)
        lineValueText.set_text('[' + lineLabel + '] = ' + str(value))


    def main(self):

        maxPlotLength = 100
        xmin = 0
        xmax = maxPlotLength
        ymin = 0
        ymax = 10

        fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12, 6), dpi=70)
        ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
        ax.set_xlim(xmin, xmax)
        ax.set_ylim(ymin, ymax)
        ax.set_title('Control de Nivel')
        ax.set_xlabel("Tiempo")
        ax.set_ylabel("Variable de Control vs Variable de Proceso")

        lineLabel = 'Set Point (Litros)'
        timeText = ax.text(0.7, 0.95, '', transform=ax.transAxes)
        lines = ax.plot([], [], linewidth=1.0, label=lineLabel)[0]
        lineValueText = ax.text(0.7, 0.90, '', transform=ax.transAxes)
        plt.legend(loc="upper left")

        plt.grid(True)

        canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=self.raiz)
        canvas.get_tk_widget().pack()
        anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, self.tag1, fargs=(lines, lineValueText, lineLabel, timeText),
                                       interval=10, blit=False)

        self.raiz.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Aplicacion()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error ultimately arises because you are appending string values into `self.data` and expecting Matplotlib to plot these strings, and it can't do that.  (Admittedly however the error message is somewhat cryptic.  I only figured it out by adding debugging lines to Matplotlib source files.)

You must ensure the values appended to `self.data` are numbers, so you will need to convert the string value from `self.entry.get()` into a number and also handle the case that the string isn't a valid number.

The simplest way to do this is in your `send` method.  Try replacing it with the following:

```
    def send(self):
        try:
            self.val = float(self.entry.get())
            print(self.val)
        except ValueError:
            messagebox.showwarning("Invalid number", "You entered an invalid number.  Please try again.")
```

You will also need to add the line `import tkinter.messagebox as messagebox`.  Feel free to translate the error message into another language.

Comment: thank you very much for the help it works wonderfully. Saludos desde Ecuador